# Unity: Animator Component has a warning dialog in play mode that result in making a humanoid character in T pose

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I have all animations working properly and game is almost complete. I am facing a very weird problem regarding a warning dialog under Animator component which probably saying some rigs have been deleted. and turn that humanoid character into T pose. however if i enable or disable "root motion " check. it start working properly.

**[What I am doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phdOb.png)**: I have a gameObject on which animator component is attached. a script that instantiate a humanoid character as a child on runtime. actually its a versus menu in which i can change opponent boxer (player). whenever I instantiate a new character , I destroy the old one and replace with new one. but problem is that new character doesn't animate rather remains idle in T pose. I have attached an image of warning dialog aswell . Need a way to go... thanks

Comment: one more thing is that whenever i disable and then enable that character, it start working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the hierarchy in runtime you must use `Rebind()`.
After instantiating your `GameObject` and placing it as a child of your animator, call `animator.Rebind();`

Comment: Thankyou so much... you just solve my problem in two words.. can't vote right now due to repute. :P but your answer is perfect... (y)

Comment: No problem! Happy developing!